# How to implement new blocks wrapping with different height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, inline

I have an interesting block position case. Please give me some advice how to implement it.

For this HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item grey">1</div>
  <div class="item purple" style="height: 150px;">2</div>
  <div class="item blue">3</div>
  <div class="item blue">4</div>
  <div class="item blue">5</div>
  <div class="item blue">6</div>
  <div class="item blue">7</div>
  <div class="item blue">8</div>
  <div class="item purple">9</div>
  <div class="item purple"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get this result:

[image: expected result]

I've already tried inline-blocks [jsfiddle-code](https://jsfiddle.net/xycrrzw1/) and got this:

[image: inline-block-result-image]

and flex [jsfiddle-code](https://jsfiddle.net/f8w34292/) - got this:

[image: flex-result-image]

Comment: Can you put block 5 in block 1?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CSS Grid solution? I'm new to CSS Grid so am not 100% certain that there isn't an even better way to do this.

CSS Grid is great because it allows you to create custom grid containers in your project and gives you more control over the the size and alignment of rows and columns within the grid.  In this example, using `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` you can determine the initial placement of the grid lines, both vertically and horizontally. You can further customize the properties of each `grid-item`, which in your case, was done for that second div (`.item:nth-child(2)`) which needed twice the height of all the other grid items.

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) for more info.

Also, as a side note, you can combine Flexbox and CSS Grid for even more flexibility with your layout.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75px 75px 75px 75px;
  grid-template-rows: 75px 75px 75px;
}
 
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  -ms-grid-row: 1 / 3 ;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item grey">1</div>
  <div class="item purple">2</div>
  <div class="item blue">3</div>
  <div class="item blue">4</div>
  <div class="item blue">5</div>
  <div class="item blue">6</div>
  <div class="item blue">7</div>
  <div class="item blue">8</div>
  <div class="item purple">9</div>
</div>
```